# Sorting entire csv by frequency of occurence in one column

Tags: python, sorting, csv, pandas, frequency

I have a large CSV file, which is a log of caller data.

A short snippet of my file:

```
CompanyName    High Priority     QualityIssue
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer2         No              User
Customer3         No              Equipment
Customer1         No              Neither
Customer3         No              User
Customer3         Yes             User
Customer3         Yes             Equipment
Customer4         No              User
```

I want to sort the entire list by the frequency of occurrence of customers so it will be like:

```
CompanyName    High Priority     QualityIssue
Customer3         No               Equipment
Customer3         No               User
Customer3         Yes              User
Customer3         Yes              Equipment
Customer1         Yes              User
Customer1         Yes              User
Customer1         No               Neither
Customer2         No               User
Customer4         No               User
```

I've tried `groupby`, but that only prints out the Company Name and the frequency but not the other columns, I also tried

```
df['Totals']= [sum(df['CompanyName'] == df['CompanyName'][i]) for i in xrange(len(df))]
```

and

```
df = [sum(df['CompanyName'] == df['CompanyName'][i]) for i in xrange(len(df))]
```

But these give me errors:

> ValueError: The wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 24

I've looked at something like this:

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
```

but this only prints out two columns, and I want to sort my entire CSV. My output should be my entire CSV sorted by the first column.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to do what you want, basically add a count column by performing a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) and then you can sort on that column:

```py
df['count'] = df.groupby('CompanyName')['CompanyName'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
df.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
  CompanyName HighPriority QualityIssue count
5   Customer3           No         User     4
3   Customer3           No    Equipment     4
7   Customer3          Yes    Equipment     4
6   Customer3          Yes         User     4
0   Customer1          Yes         User     3
4   Customer1           No      Neither     3
1   Customer1          Yes         User     3
8   Customer4           No         User     1
2   Customer2           No         User     1
```

You can drop the extraneous column using [`df.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop):

```py
df.drop('count', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  CompanyName HighPriority QualityIssue
5   Customer3           No         User
3   Customer3           No    Equipment
7   Customer3          Yes    Equipment
6   Customer3          Yes         User
0   Customer1          Yes         User
4   Customer1           No      Neither
1   Customer1          Yes         User
8   Customer4           No         User
2   Customer2           No         User
```

Answer (score 10):

The [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788726/5983976) needs a minor addition: `sort` was deprecated in favour of `sort_values` and `sort_index`.

`sort_values` will work like this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1], 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
    df['count'] = \
    df.groupby('a')['a']\
    .transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
    df.sort_values('count', inplace=True, ascending=False)
    print('df sorted: \n{}'.format(df))
```

> ```
> df sorted:
> a  b  count
> 0  1  1      2
> 2  1  3      2
> 1  2  2      1
> ```

Answer (score 9):

## Update 2021

The answers proposed by [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788726/14185615) and [Ilya K.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45135447/14185615) does not work anymore.

---

The function [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) returns a Series with the counts of unique values. But the Series that we apply the `pd.Series.value_counts` function to itself contain only one unique value due to the fact that we applied `groupby` to the DataFrame and split the **CompanyName** Series into groups of unique values earlier. Thus, the final output after we apply the function would look something like this.

```
Customer3        4
dtype: int64
```

Which is nonsense, we cannot transform a value in a Series into a whole Series. Somehow, we only need the integer `4` and not the whole Series.

---

However, we can take advantage of the `groupby` function earlier by counting the number of values in each group, transforming the whole groups into the number of values in that group, and put them together into a final **Frequency** Series.

We can replace `pd.Series.value_counts` with [`pd.Series.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html#pandas.Series.count) or just simply use the function name `count`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyName': {0: 'Customer1', 1: 'Customer1', 2: 'Customer2', 3: 'Customer3', 4: 'Customer1', 5: 'Customer3', 6: 'Customer3', 7: 'Customer3', 8: 'Customer4'}, 'HighPriority': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No', 3: 'No', 4: 'No', 5: 'No', 6: 'Yes', 7: 'Yes', 8: 'No'}, 'QualityIssue': {0: 'User', 1: 'User', 2: 'User', 3: 'Equipment', 4: 'Neither', 5: 'User', 6: 'User', 7: 'Equipment', 8: 'User'}})

df['Frequency'] = df.groupby('CompanyName')['CompanyName'].transform('count')
df.sort_values(['Frequency', 'CompanyName'], inplace=True, ascending=[False, True])
```

## Output

```
>>> df

  CompanyName HighPriority QualityIssue  Frequency
3   Customer3           No    Equipment          4
5   Customer3           No         User          4
6   Customer3          Yes         User          4
7   Customer3          Yes    Equipment          4
0   Customer1          Yes         User          3
1   Customer1          Yes         User          3
4   Customer1           No      Neither          3
2   Customer2           No         User          1
8   Customer4           No         User          1
```

Comment: To properly handle "ties" in the `Frequency` column, you should sort by `['Frequency', 'CompanyName']`.  Otherwise, it's possible that two companies with the same `Frequency` could have their rows interleaved.  (I think the OP probably wants the company names to be appear in contiguous chunks.)

Answer (score 2):

I think there must be a better way to do it, but this should work:

Preparing the data:

```
import io
data = """
CompanyName  HighPriority     QualityIssue
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer1         Yes             User
Customer2         No              User
Customer3         No              Equipment
Customer1         No              Neither
Customer3         No              User
Customer3         Yes             User
Customer3         Yes             Equipment
Customer4         No              User
"""
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), sep=r"\s+")
```

And doing the transformation:

```
# create a (sorted) data frame that lists the customers with their number of occurrences
count_df = pd.DataFrame(df.CompanyName.value_counts())

# join the count data frame back with the original data frame
new_index = count_df.merge(df[["CompanyName"]], left_index=True, right_on="CompanyName")

# output the original data frame in the order of the new index.
df.reindex(new_index.index)
```

The output:

```
    CompanyName HighPriority    QualityIssue
3   Customer3   No  Equipment
5   Customer3   No  User
6   Customer3   Yes User
7   Customer3   Yes Equipment
0   Customer1   Yes User
1   Customer1   Yes User
4   Customer1   No  Neither
8   Customer4   No  User
2   Customer2   No  User
```

It's probably not intuitive what happens here, but at the moment I cannot think of a better way to do it. I tried to comment as much as possible.

The tricky part here is that the index of `count_df` is the (unique) occurrences of the customers. Therefore, I join the index of `count_df` (`left_index=True`) with the `CompanyName` column of `df` (`right_on="CompanyName"`).

The magic here is that `count_df` is already sorted by the number of occurrences, that's why we need no explicit sorting. So all we have to do is to reorder the rows of the original data frame by the rows of the joined data frame and we get the expected result.