# Sort DataFrame by occurrence in one column, while preserving order in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort DataFrame in a similar fashion to this SO question:
[Sorting entire csv by frequency of occurence in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787391/sorting-entire-csv-by-frequency-of-occurence-in-one-column)

However, one issue I'm encountering is that the count is not guaranteed to be unique and in that case rows will be interleaved (I'm using the method suggested by EdChum in the above question)

Given the following DataFrame:

```
cluster_id,distance,url
1,0.15,aaa.com
1,0.25,bbb.com
2,0.05,ccc.com
2,0.10,ccc.com
7,0.1,abc.com
7,0.2,def.com
7,0.3,xyz.com
```

After I would like it to be:

```
cluster_id,distance,url
7,0.1,abc.com
7,0.2,def.com
7,0.3,xyz.com
1,0.15,aaa.com
1,0.25,bbb.com
2,0.05,ccc.com
2,0.10,ccc.com
```

Note that columns cluster_id and distance are still in order, after sorting by occurrence of "cluster_id"

Comment: Is that sorted in any column? (Oh, I missreaded sorry!)

Comment: @JoseA. Not sure I understand you. After sorting I hope columns cluster_id and distance are still in order, after sorting by occurrence of "cluster_id"

Comment: Yes, sorry I missreaded the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can sort by `cluster_id` and new column'G':

```
df.assign(G=df.groupby('cluster_id').cluster_id.transform('count')).sort_values(['G','cluster_id'],ascending=[False,True]).drop('G',1)
Out[248]: 
   cluster_id  distance      url
4           7      0.10  abc.com
5           7      0.20  def.com
6           7      0.30  xyz.com
0           1      0.15  aaa.com
1           1      0.25  bbb.com
2           2      0.05  ccc.com
3           2      0.10  ccc.com
```

Comment: What is new column G? Number of occurrence?

Comment: @clwen here `G=df.groupby('cluster_id').cluster_id.transform('count')`, number of occurrence

Comment: Is this stable? [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) is not really clear on it. Anyway I dont know if that's the OP's point or I missreaded it (Again).

Comment: Found a different way :-)

Answer (score 0):

`
pno dn

0   A   AA

1   B   BB

2   A   AA
`
to sort in ascending order

g.assign(G=g.groupby('dn').dn.transform('count')).sort_values(['G','dn'],ascending=[True,False]).drop('G',1)

```
pno dn
```

1   B   BB

0   A   AA

2   A   AA